# Function becomes undefined when returned

Tags: javascript, function, closures, undefined

I have:

- a dictionary (`functions`) mapping string prefixes to functions
- a function (`get()`) that returns the function mapped to a string
- a function (`check()`) that checks if there's a function mapped to a string by calling `get()` and casting it to a boolean with `!!`.

When I call `get()` with a key in `functions`, I expect that `check()` returns `true`; however, it returns `false`. I perform the dictionary lookup in `get()` and print the type of the result in both functions. Here's the weird part. The type is `function` only in `get()`; in `check()`, it's `undefined`. Apparently, the function gets erased or something when I return it. How can I make `check()` accurate?

Here's my simplified code:

```
var someObject = {
    functions: {
        "a": function () { return 0; },
        "b": function () { return 1; }
    },
    get: ( function ( someVariable ) {
        Object.keys( this.functions ).forEach( ( function ( functionKey ) {
            if ( someVariable.startsWith( functionKey ) ) {
                console.log( typeof this.functions[ functionKey ] );
                return this.functions[ functionKey];
            }
        } ).bind( this ) );
    } ),
    check: function ( stringToCheck ) {
        var returnedFunction = this.get( stringToCheck );
        console.log( typeof returnedFunction );
        return !!returnedFunction;
    }
}

$( document ).ready( function () {
    someObject.check( "a" );
} );
```

Running this code produces this:

```
"function"
"undefined"
```

in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `forEach` does not break early/short circuit on the `return` statement (it continues with the next iteration, and then the `get` function returns `undefined`). You could re-write the loop to allow breaking (say, with a simple `for-loop`), or you could return the value after looping, such as:

```
var someObject = {
    functions: {
        "a": function () { return 0; },
        "b": function () { return 1; }
    },
    get: ( function ( someVariable ) {
        var func;
        Object.keys( this.functions ).forEach( ( function ( functionKey ) {
            if ( someVariable.startsWith( functionKey ) ) {
                console.log( typeof this.functions[ functionKey ] );
                func = this.functions[ functionKey];
            }
        } ).bind( this ) );
        return func;
    } ),
    check: function ( stringToCheck ) {
        var returnedFunction = this.get( stringToCheck );
        console.log( typeof returnedFunction );
        return !!returnedFunction;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're returning the function from within the `forEach` callback. it goes nowhere.

A fix could work like Jack suggested, but the code code be simplified:

```
get: function ( someVariable ) {
        var func;
        Object.keys( this.functions ).some(function ( functionKey ) {
            if ( someVariable.startsWith( functionKey ) ) {
                console.log( typeof this.functions[ functionKey ] );
                func = this.functions[ functionKey];
                return true;
            }
        }, this );
        return func;
    }
```

- You don't need to wrap the function with parens
- You don't need to bind, `forEach` & `some` (the one I used) accept a `thisArg` parameter.
- If you use `some`, the iteration stops as soon as the callback returns true. That's more efficient in cases where there are many keys, and also more accurately matches what your original code tried to do. In Jack's version, if the keys where `['a', 'b', 'aa']`, You'd iterate all 3, and return 'aa', while your code (and mine) stops after the first 'a'.